# How to redirect angular components

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I currently have `ionic/angular` app that allows users to sign up as varying roles. Based on the role they sign up as I would like them to be redirected to a specific angular component. I have a signup form in my index.html file and the redirect logic in my `script.js` file however, I don't know how to write the redirect logic. In other words, how do I navigate to a specific component, based on the users role, from a `javascript` file?

Comment: Please go through angular routing and Navigation, https://angular.io/guide/router
It will give you a good idea for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i already did but i'm still a bit confused on what to do because my components were built with ionic, so i don't know how to redirect an ion component in javascript

Comment: Please provide some reproducible code example, so it gives a better understanding.

Comment: what you are looking for is RouteGuard, see examples. https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: are you sure you are using `Ionic/Angular` because of angular uses ts and you are trying to write routing code in `script.js`.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I picking up where someone left off, in which they wrote an application in HTML/CSS and jQuery, but they want me to finish it in ionic

Answer (score 0):

You could load a 'dispatcher' component. And decide what to load next (based on users' role). This component can be smart enough to handle the logic.